# Preferences.store() throws UnsupportedOperationException in Liferay 6.2 GA2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have a JSF portlet that was working in 6.1. When I upgraded to 6.2 CE GA2, preferences.store() throws UnsupportedOperationException. I get preferences object as follows:

```java
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

// Get portlet preferences
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
PortletPreferences portletPreferences = portletRequest.getPreferences();
```

And I have following attributes in liferay-portlet.xml:

```xml
<preferences-unique-per-layout>true</preferences-unique-per-layout>
<preferences-owned-by-group>false</preferences-owned-by-group>
```

I found some related threads and bug reports (https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42458). I can confirm that when I have true this code works. Issue is fixed but I am still getting this problem. Also I tried to implement that hook workaround but that interface seems to be changed in GA2.

Also when I get the preferences store using the following code, store() executes without exception but it seems that it is access different values than the preferences I get using the code at the beginning of the post.

```java
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

// Get portlet preferences
PortletPreferences portletPreferences = null;
try {
    portletPreferences = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(
                                portletRequest, PortletIdUtil.getPorletId());
} catch (PortalException | SystemException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(portletPreferences == null) {
    return;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm that the interface has changed. I didn't fully test, but the workaround mentioned in [LPS-42458](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42458) works for me without compiler errors. When you fix the imports on that overridden service wrapper, make sure to choose the correct SystemException, as Liferay confusingly has two of them. `com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException` was required to make the code compile for me

Comment: It seems i made a silly mistake when i try to implement that hook. As you said workaround seems to work.